# Dagger2 scope, instance per component

Tags: android, dagger-2

I'm looking for a quick confirmation about Dagger 2 scopes in Android.

In many resources online you will find that `@ActivityScope` and `@FragmentScope` are added to components that provide bindings for activities and fragments.

I would like to have some confirmation that this implies that there will be 1 instance for all activities / all fragments respectively.
That is, if, say, two activities use the same component for receiving dependencies from the same component annotated with scope 'Activity', both activities will receive the same instance (like singleton annotation would work).

So in that case having @ActivityScope and @FragmentScope annotations would only be useful to segregate between dependency lifetimes between activities versus fragments.
So if I would need a dependency object for which I need a separate instance in two activities, I should scope them explicitly (e.g. @LoginActivityScope).

Could you confirm that this assumption is correct?

**Edit:**

Reading the docs about subcomponents, it confuses me a bit:

> No subcomponent may be associated with the same scope as any ancestor
>   component, although two subcomponents that are not mutually reachable
>   can be associated with the same scope because there is no ambiguity
>   about where to store the scoped objects. (The two subcomponents
>   effectively have different scope instances even if they use the same
>   scope annotation.)

This would seem to assume that if you have multiple components using the same annotation, it does create a separate instance when the same `scope` annotation is used for different components.

I find it a bit unclear as to what a `scope instance` refers to. This actually refers to the binding?
Does this only apply to subcomponents?

Some clarification about scope vs dependency instances (bindings) would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A scoped component will create a scoped object the first time it is used, then it will hold on to it. If you create the same component a second time it will also create the scoped object the first time it gets used. Components are just objects, they don't hold any global (static) state, so if you recreate the component, you recreate everything along with it.

```
val component = DaggerScopedComponent.create()
component.getScopedObject() === component.getScopedObject() // always the same object!

// never the same object! two different components, albeit same scope
DaggerScopedComponent.create().getScopedObject() != DaggerScopedComponent.create().getScopedObject()
```

Dagger generates code, so I would invite you to create a *simple* example and have a look at the code. e.g. the sample above should be very easy to read

```
@Singleton class Foo @Inject constructor()

@Singleton @Component interface ScopedComponent {
  fun getScopedObject() : Foo
}
```

If you have a scoped component that lives longer than its subscopes then you have to keep a reference to this component and reuse it. The usual practice is to hold a reference to the component in the object whose lifecycle it shares (Application, Activity, Fragment) if needed.

Let's say we add a subcomponent to the example above

```
@Singleton class Foo @Inject constructor()

@Singleton @Component interface ScopedComponent {
    fun getScopedObject() : Foo

    fun subComponent() : SubComponent
}


@Other @Subcomponent interface SubComponent {
    fun getScopedObject() : Foo
}

@Scope
@MustBeDocumented
annotation class Other
```

As long as we use the same `@Singleton` component we will always get the same `@Singleton` scoped objects.

```
// Subcomponents will have the same object as the parent component
component.subComponent().getScopedObject() === component.getScopedObject()

// as well as different Subcomponents
component.subComponent().getScopedObject() === component.subComponent().getScopedObject()
```

Now on to your questions...

---

> I would like to have some confirmation that this implies that there will be 1 instance for all activities / all fragments respectively.
>   That is, if, say, two activities use the same component for receiving dependencies from the same component annotated with scope 'Activity', both activities will receive the same instance (like singleton annotation would work).

As shown above, any scoped object provided from the *same* scoped component will be the same no matter which subcomponent. If you create two `@ActivityScope MyActivityComponent` then everything scoped `@ActivityScoped` will be created *once per component*.

If you want objects to be shared between your Activities' components you have to use a *higher* scope and keep the reference to the created component.

---

> So in that case having @ActivityScope and @FragmentScope annotations would only be useful to segregate between dependency lifetimes between activities versus fragments.

No, because you can have a `@ActivityScope FooActivityComponent` and a `ActivityScope BarActivityComponent` and they would *never* share a `@ActivityScope class FooBar` object, which will be created once for every `@ActivityScope` scoped component.

> So if I would need a dependency object for which I need a separate instance in two activities, I should scope them explicitly (e.g. @LoginActivityScope).

`@ActivityScope FooActivityComponent` and `@ActivityScope LoginActivityComponent` will *never* share any `@ActivityScope` scoped objects. You can use the same scope here. You can also create a different scope if you like to do so, but it would make no difference here.

---

> This would seem to assume that if you have multiple components using the same annotation, it does create a separate instance when the same scope annotation is used for different components.

Yep

> I find it a bit unclear as to what a scope instance refers to. This actually refers to the binding? Does this only apply to subcomponents?

You can't have a hierarchy of components like `Singleton > ActivityScope > ActivityScope` since those duplicated scopes would make it impossible to know whether a `@ActivityScope` scoped object was part of the first or second one.

You can have two different components of the same scope, both subcomponents of the same parent (they can't "reach" each other), and any `@ActivityScope` scoped object would be part of the latter `@ActivityScope` scoped component. You'd have one scoped object per component (as shown in the example above) and you could have two component instances or more.

- `Singleton > ActivityScope FooComponent`
- `Singleton > ActivityScope BarComponent`

---

I recommend you forget about Android for a bit and just play around with Dagger and the generated code, like with the code shown on top. This is IMHO the quickest way to figure out how things work, once the "magic" is gone and you see that it's just a POJO with a few variables in it.